# How to add and print the highchart in word document from export option

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a simple highcharts,I need to add 'download word' and when I click that chart should be downloaded/exported as word format.Can anyone one please help,I have search in google but I didn't find that much options.

Here is my code:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Employees'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointStart: 2010
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Installation',
        data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
    }, {
        name: 'Manufacturing',
        data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
    }, {
        name: 'Sales & Distribution',
        data: [11744, 17722, 16005, 19771, 20185, 24377, 32147, 39387]
    }, {
        name: 'Project Development',
        data: [null, null, 7988, 12169, 15112, 22452, 34400, 34227]
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Can anyone suggest a way to do it manually or with the help of any third party plugin ?.Here is the code below.

Comment: You can try exporting feature and it will  export as image https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133645/run-highcharts-on-server-side-code-to-add-to-word-document

Comment: Unfortunately, Highcharts doesn't provide word document format export. However, you can check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802011/exporting-several-highcharts-graphs-to-powerpoint-slides with powerpoint format export explanation and you can try to implement it for word format.